# C++: Large multidimensional vector causes seg fault

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I have a large file (50x11k) of a grid of numbers. All i am trying to do is place the values into a vector so that i can access the values of different lines at the same time. I get a seg fault everytime (i cannot even do a cout before a the while loop). Anyone see the issue?

If there is an easier way to do this then please let me know. Its a large file and I need to be able to compare the values of one row with another so a simple getline does not work, Is there a way to jump around a file and not "grab" the lines, but just "examine" the lines so that I can later go back an examine that same line by putting in that number? Like looking at the file like a big array? I wanna look at the third line and 5 character in that line at the same time i look at the 56th line and 9th character, something like that.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//int g_Max = 0;

int main() {

    vector<vector<string> > grid;

    ifstream in("grid.txt");
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    string c;

    if (!in) {
        cout << "NO!";
    }

    while (!in.eof()) {
        c = in.get();
        if ( c.compare("\n") == 0) {
            row++;
            column = 0;
        }
        else {
            c = grid[column][row];
            cout << grid[column][row];
            column++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't resized the vector before you try to access its elements

Comment: Whenever you say `.eof()`, it's probably wrong.

Comment: If you have a grid of numbers, why are you using a string? For reference 500000 long integrals are about 3.8M megabyte, which isn't much.

Comment: its ok to put it all into vector, maybe parsing might take some time

Comment: There is also nothing in grid for you to assign c too before the cout

Comment: As an aside, a vector of vectors is a bad idea if it is going to contain a lot of data that needs to be iterated over.  Each vector will allocate its own separate data store, so you'll end up hopping all over memory while iterating and losing advantages that the cache would give you.  Best to allocate one big vector and calculate the offset to each element manually (assumes that each sub-vector would be the same size though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    vector<vector<string> > grid;
```

This declares an empty vector, with no elements.

```
        c = grid[column][row];
```

This accesses elements of the vector, but there are no elements.

If you change it to use `vector::at()` instead of `vector::operator[]` like so:

```
        c = grid.at(column).at(row);
```

then you'll get exceptions telling you you're accessing out of range.

You need to populate the vector with elements before you can access them.  One way is to declare it with the right number of elements up front:

```
    vector<vector<string> > grid(11000, std::vector<string>(50));
```

You probably also want to fix your IO loop, testing `!in.eof()` is usually wrong. Why not read a line at a time and split the line up, instead of reading single characters?

```
while (getline(in, c))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the meaty answer!

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to access all lines at once why you don't declare it as `std::vector<std::string>` and each line is an `string`??

```
std::string s;
std::vector<std::string> lines;
while( std::getline(in, s) ) lines.push_back( s );
std::cout << "File contain " << lines.size() << " line" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Char at [1][2] is " << lines[1][2] << std::endl; // assume [1][2] is valid!
```